# Xcode 9, iOS 11, XCUITest failure: Main Thread Checker Flurry Analytics

Tags: automation, ios10, swift4, xcode9, xcuitest

Running my suite of XCUITests using Xcode 9 running on iOS 11.

Tests all run perfect in Xcode 8 (iOS10), but in Xcode 9 I get the following error:

```
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on background thread [UIApplication statusBarOrientation]... 
... Queue name: com.Flurry.Analytics.Session
```

This can be fixed by commenting out all the Flurry code, but that is obviously not ideal.  This issue has been seen by devs previously:
https://github.com/flurry/flurry-ios-sdk/issues/91

However, in this case, the dev build compiles all correctly and this error only occurs when XCUITests are run.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

To avoid crash in test you have to uncheck `Main Thread Checker` in your Scheme

Go `Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes` search the Scheme you use for your tests and press `Edit...` in the left sidebar press `Test` and then go to `Diagnostics` and uncheck `Main Thread Checker` checkbox

And try again

This is a temporal solution and you should try to avoid call UI API on background threads because the app could behave weirdly. But since you use third-party library you should wait until they fix it.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I tried that the other day but still getting the same errors.  Even restarted xcode afterwards, but still no joy.

Comment: I expect a sdk release for Flurry next week that will address this issue.