# UI API called on a background thread com.google.Maps.LabelingBehavior

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

After upgrading to XCode 9 I suddently get the following warning when I run my app:

```
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIApplication applicationState]
PID: 15473, TID: 773864, Thread name: com.google.Maps.LabelingBehavior, Queue name: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit, QoS: 21
Backtrace:
4   App                          0x000000010b8ee524 GMSIsApplicationInBackground + 53
5   App                          0x000000010b8dc77a -[GMSForegroundDispatchQueue initWithName:targetQueue:] + 269
6   App                          0x000000010b9bc5ee _ZN7gmscore6vector4text8GlyphSetC2ERKNS_4base10reffed_ptrINS0_16TextureAtlasPoolEEEPU28objcproto17OS_dispatch_queue8NSObjectPK8__CTFontff + 344
7   App                          0x000000010b9bba58 _ZN7gmscore6vector4text10GlyphCache11GetGlyphSetEPK8__CTFontf + 214
8   App                          0x000000010b9b950e _ZN7gmscore6vector4text6GLText14PrefetchGlyphsERKNS_4base10reffed_ptrINS1_10GlyphCacheEEERKNSt3__16vectorItNS9_9allocatorItEEEEPK8__CTFontf + 22
9   App                          0x000000010b9b9611 _ZN7gmscore6vector4text6GLText14PrefetchGlyphsERKNS_4base10reffed_ptrINS1_10GlyphCacheEEEPK8__CTLinebf + 207
10  App                          0x000000010b9112df _ZN7gmscore6vector12GLPointLabel22PrefetchGlyphsForGroupEPNS0_12GLLabelGroupE + 181
11  App                          0x000000010b911207 _ZN7gmscore6vector12GLPointLabel14PrefetchGlyphsEv + 33
12  App                          0x000000010b98022a _ZN7gmscore6vector16LabelingBehavior23CreatePendingOperationsERKNSt3__13setINS_4base10reffed_ptrINS0_7GLLabelEEENS2_4lessIS7_EENS2_9allocatorIS7_EEEESE_SE_NS0_13LabelDrawModeE + 1096
13  App                          0x000000010b97fb9d _ZN7gmscore6vector16LabelingBehavior14RunLabelingJobERKNS_4base10reffed_ptrINS1_11LabelingJobEEE + 357
14  App                          0x000000010b97fa2a ___ZN7gmscore6vector16LabelingBehavior14CommitInternalEPNS_8renderer14EntityRendererE_block_invoke + 22
15  Foundation                          0x0000000110bb0948 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 334
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001117af2b1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011184ed31 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
18  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111793c19 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001117931ff __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000111792a89 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
21  Foundation                          0x0000000110b6ae5e -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 274
22  App                                 0x000000010b9bace5 -[GMSx_GTMSimpleWorkerThread main] + 337
23  Foundation                          0x0000000110b788ac __NSThread__start__ + 1197
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011323393b _pthread_body + 180
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000113233887 _pthread_body + 0
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000011323308d thread_start + 13
Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)"
```

I can narrow it down to the problem happens when I assign the map to my view.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
    GPSManager.instance.startGPS()
    setupLayout()


    map = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: getCamera(location: initialLocation, zoom: 10))
    map.mapType = .hybrid
    map.delegate = self
    map.settings.consumesGesturesInView = false

    self.view.addSubview(map) <-- This is where is goes wrong
    self.view.sendSubview(toBack: map)

    configureMenus()
}
```

Is this something I can fix or is it inside Google Maps? Cheers

Comment: Could you add your code?

Comment: @IvanSmetanin Done

Comment: The problem is with the Google Maps SDK. You have to wait until they update their sdk :(

Comment: Also discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46333235/issues-after-updating-to-ios11-and-xcode9-com-google-maps-labelingbehavior

Answer (score 4):

The problem is inside the Google library.

If you don't want this kind of warning you can disable Main Thread Checker inside the Scheme options.

Go `Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes` search the Scheme you use for your tests and press `Edit...` in the left sidebar press `Run` and then go to `Diagnostics` and uncheck `Main Thread Checker` checkbox.

This is only a temporal solution if you don't want these warnings. I do not recommend it because you could introduce bugs if call UI inside a background thread

If you have test you should disable the checkbox in `Test` option as I explained in [Xcode 9, iOS 11, XCUITest failure: Main Thread Checker Flurry Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46360291/xcode-9-ios-11-xcuitest-failure-main-thread-checker-flurry-analytics/46361180#46361180) if you do not want the tests crash

Comment: So essentially I could turn of warnings and turn them back on, when Google updates?

Comment: Yes, but if you play a lot with threads and UIKit its better have the warnings turned on to avoid weird behaviors. I'd recommend you to let active in `Run` and disabled in `Test` until Google updates it.

Comment: Could I push my app with this problem to the App Store? It doesn't seem to break anything in the app.

Comment: Yes, you could do that.